# Multi-step creation wizard using AJAX and JQuery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm in the process of redesigning a creation wizard in our ASP.NET MVC 2 application.

Our current method is to have different pages for each step and navigate between them. While this works, it's a bit slow and annoying to navigate.

I was looking to use JQuery and AJAX to make this feel a bit more dynamic and to also use client side validation.

I have investigated using `Ajax.BeginForm()` to post back the individual steps of the wizard, and have that post return the partial view containing the new form with the next step of the wizard. That way, I can do client-side validation on each step.

With this in mind, is `Ajax.BeginForm()` a better method than using the [JQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)? Has anyone found any major issues with either approach?

Does anyone have any other suggestions i haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put a footnote on this, I ended up not using a wizard and redesigned the creation process using AJAX loading, jQuery UI widgets and a lot of manual jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this?  [Form Wizard](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/formwizard) It breaks down large forms into multiple steps and AJAX moves through the steps automatically.  I have looked at in briefly, but don't have alot of experience with it.  Let me know if you try it and if it is any good :)